# Do I have to uninstall Xampp before install Zend Server?

Tags: xampp, zend-server

I newly installled Flash Builder for PHP which provide nice intergration with Zend. So I want to switch to Zend Server. My XAMPP has been running fine, I wouldn't uninstall it if it wouldn't bother Zend Server, or I may uninstall it when I really feel good with Zend Server. Can I have them both in the same computer?

Answer (score 0):

If you install it on a different port, it should run fine.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to install Zend Server for use Zend AMF.

You can use Zend with xampp if you want.